# Android: Updating Fragments (that might not yet be created) from activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Is there any way to do this?

I'm working on an application that uses multiple tabs to manage bluetooth connections, messages and other stuff.

I need my activity to inform each of these tabs (fragments) of certain events such as connection status, messages delivered.

I used an approach where i keep a reference to each of my fragments in the adapter. The problem is that fragments are not instantiated until o switch to the tab that uses it.

Is it possible to instantiate all four fragments so that i can update their view even though it has not been shown yet?

Thanks a lot,

and sorry for my english

Comment: You can instantiate them with `new`, but be warned they may not be in a consistent state until the framework has has the opportunity to call `onCreate()` and other lifecycle methods of those fragments. If that's not important to what you want to update, then I think you can do so safely.

Comment: that was my first try. it behaves as null, throws an exception and closes the app.

Comment: *"Is it possible to instantiate all four fragments so that i can update their view even though it has not been shown yet?"* - Why would you want to do that? What's the point of updating something that isn't visible? In stead, you should keep the state of the app somewhere. Then when the fragment(s) actually get created, they'll be able to update based on that state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a ViewPager (you mentioned "tabs") just call [setOffscreenPageLimit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) in onCreate() of your App (after initializing ViewPager). Set the limit to the number of your fragments. With this all of your fragments will be instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using frames, and then populating each one with a fragment when the time is right. When you get to the correct tab, do a null check to see if the frame is actually a part of the layout. If it is present 
then place the fragment in the frame. That should do it.